# Styling the text outline in QT‘s tabs

Tags: qt, text, tabs, stylesheet, outline

When I switch system themes, I find themes in which the text has an outline that I don’t want, for active tabs.
¿

[image]

I cannot figure any way to style that outline and make it disappear so the tabs text will look cleaner like this.
[image]

Is this possible? I have tried already with stylesheets using `outline: 0;` and nothing happens.

Reimplementing the paint event perhaps? but no idea about the exact code to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would truthfully leave the theming alone. If the user likes the theme with those outlines, then I think the user would prefer uniform application looks.

Comment: @Blender first I want to tell you that you are my favorite 3d modelling application. I have used you for years.
Well, about your comment, the strange thing is that GTK apps won’t show this outline when QT applications do. I actually don’t know whose fault it is of.

Comment: Lol, thanks. I don't use it much anymore (no reason to, truthfully), but it is still my favorite 3D modelling/animating/simulation program money can't buy. As for the tabs, I get the outlines on GTK+ applications (this is Nautilus): http://i.imgur.com/dSrQs.png. But I can see what I can do...

Comment: lol, you are welcome. As for the tabs... what style are you using? I am using Clearlooks.

Comment: +1 at Blender's first comment. Not playing around with themes is a good practice. But if you really want to control this little thing, you'll have to subclass QStyle and take a look at `QTabBar::initStyleOption()` source code to figure out how and why this outline appears

Answer (score 1):

I was browsing qt-sources and i think what you describe is a focus rect. It should be visible only if tab bar has a focus (or does it behave differently?). Removing it would be confusing to user as he would not see currently focused widget when tab-scrolling throught the window. Making tab bar not-focusing at all might be a solution, but then user will lose ability to change tabs by keyboard.

If you really want to remove it, i would suggest to subclass QProxyStyle, and reimplement drawPrimitive method, so for QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect it doesn't do anything, and for other elements call QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive.

EDIT:

I tested this approach, and it didn't work - when i have a moment i will try to figure out why.

EDIT2:

After long investigation I figured out why QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect doesn't work. It appears that focus rectangle is drawn by style directly, bypassing proxy styles completely. The smallest reimplementable code is drawPrimitve for CE_TabBarTabLabel element, but it requires painting tab's labels yourself, which really shouldn't be done in multi-style environment, so thiss not the way to go.

After further examination of code for CleanLooks style (I don't seem to have mentioned Ambiance - or am I making stupid mistake here?) I am sure that qt designers didn't allow such surgical approach to styles - if style wants to paint a frame, there is little to be done to prevent it.

Playing with palette colors to make such frame to "blend in" is almost impossible because other styles might interpret those values differently, causing even worse look. Cleanlooks dreives almost all colors used from palette's button color and it's darker() or lighter() versions, so even for one style it is impossible.

I also tried to see if I can get rid of this frame using qt-stylesheet engine, but whatever stylesheets I used, frame was still drawn without noticable change. After looking int qt source code again it turned out that code drawing this frame is stylesheet-unaware.

The only aproach that I found working quite well, was to cheat style into thinking that drawn tab is not focused at all. Code I came up with is:

```
class myStyle: public QProxyStyle{
public:
    myStyle(QStyle* baseStyle)
        :QProxyStyle(baseStyle){}

    virtual void drawControl ( ControlElement element, const QStyleOption * option, QPainter * painter, const QWidget * widget = 0 ) const{

        if (element == CE_TabBarTabLabel){
            if (const QStyleOptionTab *tb = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionTab *>(option)) {
                if (tb->state & State_HasFocus){
                    QStyleOptionTab t(*tb);
                    t.state = t.state^State_HasFocus;
                    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, &t, painter, widget);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
    }
};
```

Setting such style on tabBar() widget causes right style to be used, and tab is drawn without any focus rectangles. tabBar() is protected method, so you will need to create class inherinig QTabWidget.

While this solution works, it cannot be called pretty. It is cheating style, by providing false information. I don't think it will lead to some ugly artifacts, as widget is just drawing itself as usual (non-focused). However, user usually expects to see where keyboard-focus actually is (especially if all other apps are showing it on tabs), so it might be confusing. If I were to choose, I would prefer consitency over looks.

As I have written in the first part of my answer (before edits), you can also call setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus) on your tab widget, so it simply doesn't accept focus at all. It might be even reccomended eg. if your tabs are in dock widgets docked to main window.

Comment: I will try this when I can, for now you deserve the 500 points for all the work you did. Thanks for this useful information.